# How to have 2 versions of flutter like(stable, beta) or (2.0.0, 1.22.6)?

Tags: flutter

Basically, I want to have 2 versions of flutter & want to switch between them as fast & easy as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Flutter Version Manager](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm).  Allows you to have as many Flutter versions installed as you want and to switch between them instantly (via symbolic links).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a slow solution that:

1. I can copy my flutter folder paste it into another location
2. turn the other copy to beta if u need or (v 1.22.6)
3. then change flutter SDK path from the android studio or vs code